# How to rewrite a URL if its character length is less than a certain number of characters

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following code in my .htaccess file that allows URLs that contain only letters, numbers, underscores or dashes to access my page (named "available"):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$ /available.shtml [L]
```

So for example, mywebsite.com/abc goes through, mywebsite.com/ABC goes through, mywebsite.com/123 goes through, mywebsite.com/aBc123 goes through (you get the point). Any requested url that contains *symbols* produces an error page.

This works great, but I also want to restrict the character length to no more than 25 characters (Meaning the requested URL must contain only letters, numbers, etc. AND be *less* than 25 characters long. How can I do this? I tried using:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{25,})+$ /available.shtml [L]
```

but this makes it have to be *more* than 25 characters not less.

**edit** (referring to comment):
[image: error when adding period]

Comment: Check your Apache `error.log` and find out what is exact cause of this 500 error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set the upper bound:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^[\w-]{0,25}$ /available.shtml [L]
```

Instead of `0,25`, you could also try `1,25` if you want `http://yoursite.com` to also be sent to `/available` page.

Comment: wait why is there a [\w–] what does that do?

Comment: @Cris `\w` is same as writing `a-zA-Z0-9_`, however, `\w` also takes care of similar ranges in other language symbols (like french/german etc.)

Comment: Works great thanks, is there a way to also include periods? When I put [\w-.], [\w.-], or [\w-\.] I get an internal server error for all inputted URLs

Comment: The `[\w.-]` should work. `-` should be either the first or last character in set, otherwise it works as a range.

Comment: Hmm it still doesn't work. I updated my post, this is the error I receive for all URLs now (URLs that do and do not contain periods)

Comment: @Cris do you have other rules? I think it might be because `available.shtml` also meets the pattern. If you are on httpd v2.4+, set the flag to `[L,END]`

Comment: No other rules, I thought it may have been but I isolated the code and still didn't work. I also tried replacing `[L]` with `[L, END]` but gave me the same error.

Comment: Do check your server and error log files for the issue.

Comment: Just checked it and all it said was, well pretty much nothing. It said it is due to a problem in the configuration file. It's ok, I'm not going to stress it. Thanks for your help, I did get what I was originally looking for!